# returning matched value while using grep

Tags: r, string, text

I am using `grep` function to identify if a list of string(or a col of string) is partially present in a particular col(query) or not.

```
test$result <- sapply(test$query,function(x) ifelse(grep(paste(listofstring,collapse="|"),x),1,0))
```

Is there any way to get the matched string instead of binary output?

For example:

```
listofstring <- c("Mac","Windows","Linux","Android")
test <- data.frame(query = c("I love Mac","I love Ubuntu","I love Android","I love both Android and Linux"))
```

Using above code I am able to get the output as :

```
Query                               Result
I love Mac                            1
I love Ubuntu                      logical(0)
I love Android                         1
I love both Android and Linux          1
```

But what I actually want is the matched value and desired output as :

```
Query                              Result
I love Mac                          Mac
I love Ubuntu                       N/A
I love Android                     Android
I love both Android and Linux      Android
I love both Android and Linux       Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
stack(setNames(lapply(str_extract_all(test$query, 
      paste(listofstring,collapse="|")), function(x)
      if(length(x)==0) NA else x), test$query))[2:1]
#                            ind  values
#1                    I love Mac     Mac
#2                 I love Ubuntu    <NA>
#3                I love Android Android
#4 I love both Android and Linux Android
#5 I love both Android and Linux   Linux
```

---

Using the string in the comments

```
str1 <- "a b c d e f g h"
str_match_all(str1, "(?=(a b|b c|c d))")[[1]][,2]
#[1] "a b" "b c" "c d"
```

Comment: Can we also switch positioning of the column ?

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal  Isn't this the same as the one in your expected output?

Comment: I forgot you switched them. My bad, Got it. 
Let's see if it works on my data as data size is 300MB.

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal  If it is really big dataset, use `melt` from `data.table`

Comment: Can you help here to do the same thing with melt. yes data size is very large. 300mb+

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal  Just replace `stack` with `melt`. that is all.

Comment: Sure, it is done and thankfully it is working fine with data as large as 1GB. However it is also doing partial search. What i mean is if i change `listofstring` to 
`listofstring <- c("Mac","Windows","Linux","Android","a","b")`
 it will still populate matching entry. I want only exact match. Please guide me.

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal  You can use word boundary (`\\b`) i.e. `paste0("\\b(", paste(listofstring, collapse="|"), ")\\b")`

Comment: I am using your code but just now i caught an error in it. 
Refer below code :
`t=as.list(c("a b","b c","c d"))`

`str_extract_all("a b c d e f g h",paste0("\\b(", paste(t, collapse="|"), ")\\b"))`

expected output is `"a b","b c","c d"`

why so?

Comment: @vk087 I was answering this based on the example you showed.

Comment: Yes I got your point but it is not working when I am using `t=as.list(c("a b","b c","c d"))` I think `str_extract_all` is dropping string after each iteration. How can we overcome this ? I have implemented this in a large system. Please help me here.

Comment: I am not able to find a solution to fix this issue. Kindly help.